# How to navigate page number in word 2016?

Tags: microsoft-word, navigation

I know I can go to "Navigation" - "Pages" and scroll down the side panel to certain pages. But can I directly go to a particular page by typing the page number?

Comment: press F5 and you can go to anywhere by any type of anchors, and it works in any MS Word version, not only 2016]

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the search box (e.g. Ctrl + F), then in the "Find and Replace" box, find "Go To" and "Page". Type the page number there.

Comment: Super User is looking for well developed and complete answers. Although your answer may be correct, it is very low quality. Please take a minute to explain your answer with some detail. You can find more information in the [help].

Comment: How about now? I edited

Comment: Much better. Thanks for taking the time to improve it.